# Cannot get simple PHP function to execute

Tags: php, html

I've written the function as such and now it returns "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign" even if I select no boxes or just one or two. I'm assuming the problem is in the if statement, do I need to run isset twice?

```
function adMix () {
$tv = (isset($_POST['TV']));
$radio = (isset($_POST['Radio']));
$search = (isset($_POST['Search']));
$mobile = (isset($_POST['Mobile']));
$mail = (isset($_POST['Mail']));
if ($tv || $radio || $search || $mobile || $mail) {
    echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
} else {
    echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
}
```

}

Comment: Your first letter in the HTML is always uppercase while the ones in the PHP code are always lowercase. Even it out and try again.

Comment: Also fix the blind assignments (`$tv = $_POST['tv'];`): you're performing the `isset` check on the variables instead of the `$_POST` keys, which _will_ produce notices...

Comment: Form data is send CaseSenSitive.. `name="Mail"` will come through as `$_POST['Mail']`

Answer (score 0):

Try making the checkboxes behave as an array, renaming them all to `mktg[]`, per example:

```
<p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="mktg[]" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mktg[]" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mktg[]" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mktg[]" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="mktg[]" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
<br>
```

And the function:

```
function adMix(){
    if($_POST){
       if(!empty($_POST['mktg'])){
           if(count($_POST['mktg'])) echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
       }else echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
}
```

This way, `if(count($_POST['mktg']))` verifies if any option was checked and returns true. If you need to define how many options must be selected to the campaing be true, let's say 3, just do this:

```
if(count($_POST['mktg']) >= 3)
```

Comment: I tried this one out and it did not work, it still keeps echoing "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign" regardless of what I select.

Comment: With my pure example, even if you select only one it will echo this message, this is no error. But as I said above, if user has a minimal options to check to show it, just change the `if`

Comment: I understand your answer in theory but when I ran it and only selected one, or none of the options, it still echoed "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign."

Comment: Right, I changed now the else, it was in the wrong place. Now it returns 'you can do more...' message if you don't check any option.

Comment: It shows You are running a comprehensive ad campaign regardless of what I select.

Comment: Yes, that's right... What is being shown if you don't select any?

Comment: The same thing as if you select them all.

Comment: Have you checked my fiddle above? If you click send without selecting any option, it returns the 'false' message. Otherwise, returns the 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

```
function adMix () {
  if (isset($_POST['Tv']) || isset($_POST['Radio']) || isset($_POST['Search']) || isset($_POST['Mobile']) || isset($_POST['Mail'])) {
    $tv = isset($_POST['Tv'])?$_POST['Tv']:""; //You can access the index only if it's set, else you will be shown a notice
    $radio = isset($_POST['Radio'])?$_POST['Radio']:"";
    $search = isset($_POST['Search'])?$_POST['Search']:"";
    $mobile = isset($_POST['Mobile'])?$_POST['Mobile']:"";
    $mail = isset($_POST['Mail'])?$_POST['Mail']:"";
    echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
  } else {
    echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one out and it did not work, it still keeps echoing "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign" regardless of what I select.

Comment: Even if you don't select anything ?

Comment: You would get only that even if any one of the above field is selected. Plus, if any of these field is a text field, you will always have the same thing echoed

Comment: They are all checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, even if I select nothing, it returns the same message.

Comment: Both your updated question and my answer for the previous version look logically correct. Can you var_dump inside the function check what the array has?

Answer (score -3):

try with this:

```
function adMix () { 
@$tv = $_POST['TV'];
@$radio = $_POST['Radio'];
@$search = $_POST['Search'];
@$mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
@$mail = $_POST['Mail'];
if (isset($tv) || isset($radio) || isset($search) || isset($mobile) || isset($mail)) {
    echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
} else {
    echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
}
}
```

Comment: what is with all the `@`'s before the variables?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. The issue is with case sensitivity.